# Vector Formatting for Display Racket

Tags: vector, matrix, formatting, racket

I've made a multidimensional vector using a vector of vectors like so:

```
#(#(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 23 1 1 1))
```

I want to know if there are any Racket functions that can help me output it like:

```
(1 1  1 1 1)
(1 1  1 1 1)
(1 1  1 1 1) 
(1 1  1 1 1)
(1 23 1 1 1)
```

(NOTE: the spacing change caused by 23)

I've been reading the documentation and haven't been able to find anything.  If I need to write my own function for it, any idea how I would implement such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scheme, you can do that simply using a for loop:

```
(for ([i vector])
    (display (vector->list i))
       (display "\n"))
```

Meanwhile, if you need some format here:

```
(displayln (string-join (for/list ([j (vector->list i)]) 
            (~a j #:width (count-digits (* n n)) #:align 'right))))

(define (count-digits a) (if (< a 10) 1 (+ 1 (count-digits (/ a 10)))))
```

which display the elements one by one with **flexible** width.

Comment: If I did that, I would be able to get them to show up one after the other, but what about getting that spacing?  Notice the spacing of the third column.

Comment: Please check the updated answer about getting that spacing. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One way to pretty print a two-dimensional list is writing a simple procedure:

```
(define (print-2-dim-list lol)
  (define (transpose xss)
    (apply map list xss))
  (define t (transpose lol))
  (define list-of-max-len (map (λ (l) (foldr (λ (x v) (max (string-length (format "~a" x)) v)) 0 l)) t))
  (printf "(\n")
  (for ([row lol])
    (printf "(")
    (for ([x row]
          [max-len list-of-max-len])
      (printf "~a" x)
      (for ([n (+ 1 (- max-len (string-length (format "~a" x))))])
        (printf "~a" #\space)))
    (printf ")\n")
    )
  (printf ")\n"))


(print-2-dim-list (map vector->list (vector->list #(#(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 23 1 1 1)))))

(
(1 1  1 1 1 )
(1 1  1 1 1 )
(1 1  1 1 1 )
(1 1  1 1 1 )
(1 23 1 1 1 )
)
```

Another way is using [text-table](https://docs.racket-lang.org/text-table/) by Laurent Orseau, which now has supported custom border styles.

```
(displayln
 (table->string (map vector->list (vector->list #(#(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 1 1 1 1) #(1 23 1 1 1))))
                #:border-style
                '(#\space ("(" " " ")")
                  ("(" "" "")
                  ("" "" "")
                  (")" "" ""))
                #:framed? #t
                #:row-sep? #f
                #:align  '(left)))

(      
(1 1  1 1 1)
(1 1  1 1 1)
(1 1  1 1 1)
(1 1  1 1 1)
(1 23 1 1 1)
)
```